# How to automate replacing "aaa-bbb-ccc" to aaa_bbb_ccc

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to replace any string with format`"XXX-XX-XXX"` to `XXX_XX_XXX` with the help of macros or live templates?
Where `X` - any symbol or digit.
For example:

`"aaa-bbb-ccc"` transforms to `aaa_bbb_ccc`

In other worlds, how can I automate the following steps:

1. I select any text fragment
2. I execute the macros or live template by some hot-key
3. The macros removes all `"` characters in the selection
4. The macros replaces all `-` characters in the selection by `_` character

Comment: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162-string-manipulation

Comment: Meo, thanks for the answer. But this plugin allows to replace `-` to `_` only. But I want to automate two actions of replacing with the help of macros or live template..

Comment: What about replacing "([A-Za-z0-9]+)-([A-Za-z0-9]+)-([A-Za-z0-9]+)" to $1_$2_$3 ?

Comment: You can do both with https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7282-liveplugin - make a groovy script using transformSelectedText template